# jQuery and jQuery UI upgrade breaks tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, typo3, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a website using the jQuery UI Tabs widget, and it works just fine with "ye old versions", jQuery: 1.5.1, jQuery UI: 1.8.4.

Doing other changes/upgrades to the site, I wanted to move to more recent versions of both packages, going at it by upgrading to "next major version" for each of them in steps. Without changing more than a few lines of my own js-code, I could get to jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.8.24, everything still working fine.

Upgrading jQuery to 1.9.1, clicking on tabs seems to trigger a reload of the page instead of switching tab. All tabs are static, so there shouldn't be any ajax-problems.

The URL for the page (it's all part of a Typo3 installation) has this format:

```
https://server.some.where/?id=49&project_id=13&action_type=display
```

When clicking a tab, a HTTP GET for the base href + #tab-X is made:

```
https://server.some.where/#tabs-2
```

As earlier versions of jQuery didn't initiate a HTTP GET, but happily switched tabs instead, I'm stumped. Reading through the changelogs for the relevant jQuery releases, I can't see anything that matches, but that might just be me... :-)

Upgrading jQuery UI (1.9.2/1.10.2) creates another problem - all tabs are open from scratch instead (all divs displayed one after another).

Relevant HTML:

> ```
> <div id="display-tabs">
>   <ul class="tabs">
>     <li><a href="#tabs-1">...</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#tabs-2">...</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#tabs-3">...</a></li>
>   </ul>
>   <div id="tabs-1">...</div>
>   <div id="tabs-2">...</div>
>   <div id="tabs-3">...</div>
> </div>
> ```

Activation of the tabs widget is dead simple:

> $('#display-tabs').tabs();

jQuery is fetched from Google, also seems fine:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
> ```

I've been eliminating most other uses of jQuery on the test-site temporarily, but these issues seems to stick. Any ideas welcome...

Comment: Is `$('#display-tabs').tabs();` inside a document ready? For example, `$(function(){ $("#display-tabs").tabs(); });`

Comment: Also, `https://ajax.googleapis.com` should just be `//ajax.googleapis.com` (See http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless for reasons)

Comment: Yep @Mooseman, the `$("#display-tabs").tabs();` line is partnered with a few hundred friends, placed within a working `$(function(){});`

Comment: seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu2kn/

Comment: And you're right, I should skip the protocol for those links. Don't think it'll help the main issue, though...

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Pete: I know - the basic code is dead simple, and "should just work". But swapping jQuery version breaks it for me...

Comment: @Mooseman: Nope, sorry about that. It's a locked down testenvironment (living happily as yet another virtual machine on my workstation... :-)

Comment: @Mooseman: I could share (mail) a copy of the page and the js, but that's about it...

Comment: I'm just saying it's not a latest version jquery problem - it will be some conflict with another plugin or stylesheet that will be causing your issue

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Can you remove all jQuery script, but leave jQuery and jQuery UI in the header? Then run `$("#display-tabs").tabs();` from the console. As @Pete said, there could be a conflict with something else.

Comment: @Mooseman: I tested dropping all js/jQuery-code except the line that attaches tabs() to my selected id. The problem stays the same, however... Tabs can be switched while using jQuery 1.8.3, but using 1.9.1 the switch is immediately followed by a GET-request for the main page of the site. I wonder if it's the base href that's messing things up...? Time to test that! :-)

Comment: Can you use the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: @Mooseman: Well, 1.9.1 is the latest vesion of jQuery (at least from Googles CDN, which I'm bound to). As for my main problem, it seems to be a known "feature" that changed from 1.8.X -> 1.9.X. jQuery got a lot stricter on usage of the base-tag, so if you're using that, anchors in your tabs aren't seen as local to the active page, instead a `GET $BASEHREF/#tabs-X` is done. This might be a more correct behaviour, but it breaks a lot of sites, especially for people using framweorks. See: [link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7822)

Comment: OK, problem solved. As I can't remove the base-tag (our Typo3-setup relies on it) I had to supply full links `//$HTTP_HOST/$REQUEST_URI#tab-X` in the list that defines the tabs. Easily done server-side, and now I can use the latest versions (1.9.1/1.10.2). Annoyingly hard to find the cause and the solution, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a known one, but it took me a while to connect the dots and use the correct search terms - sorry about that!

In short, jQuery from version 1.9 and upwards treats the combination of `<base href="URL">` and links to anchors `<a href="#tab-X">` as a link that **isn't** local to the page. This behaviour might be more correct than what happened in earlier versions, but it's a change that breaks a lot of sites built on frameworks that relies on base-tags. My local solution was to supply full links in the list that defines the tabs, like this: `//$HTTP_HOST/$REQUEST_URI#tab-X`.

More info on the issue:

- [jQuery UI bug 7822](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7822)
- [Fairly good explanation & some solutions](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/02/17/using-jquery-ui-tabs-with-the-base-tag/)